# openCV is not found when importing

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylance

I am just starting in python and am trying to experiment with cv2, but whenever I try to import it I get the same error:

```
Import "cv2" could not be resolved
```

I have tried every possible way of installing it, I have tried

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python39/site-packages)
```

which I've seen on one of the posts, I have also swapped between versions (tried 3.7). When I try it in pycharm, and I hover ower it because it gives me an error and an option to install it where I get an error named

```
Non-zero exit code (2)
```

Pycharm image:
[image: pycharm image]

Vscode image:
[image: vscode image]

Answer (score 2):

You're using wrong command to install the library. Always check the command on a website with corresponding package documentation like this one: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

So the command you need will be

`pip install opencv-python`

if this still doesn't work, try different variations:

`pip3 install opencv-python`

or

`python -m pip install opencv-python`

Comment: I have already tried all the suggested commands but it still doesn't work

Comment: Do you have a virtualenv set up? And where do you run these commands?

Comment: I do, I run them in cmd....did also tried in the VSCode terminal. it says that it installed and other libraries from the same folder work

Comment: I Can see you used PyCharm. Try PyCharm's terminal. Also try switching to virtualenv's directory before running the commands (but for me it works without specifying the directory in PyCharm). Also, for PyCharm, don't forget to specify project interpreter (by deafult, right top corner of window, next to "run" button)